# Weak Boundness in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: functional-analysis

"Consider $(\mathbb{R}^n,|\cdot|)$ and let $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ be its canonical basis. $B$ is bounded in $\mathbb{R}^n$ iff there exists $M$ such that 
$$ |(e_i,x)|=|x_i|\le M\qquad\forall x\in B,\forall i\in\{1,\dots,n\}" $$
I can't understand why he's considering only the elements of the basis.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? It's a theorem.

Comment: The idea is that each of the elements in the basis represents a "direction" in that space. This theorem is basically saying that for a set to be bounded, you just need to check that all the components of each point in the set are bounded in each direction.

Comment: It kinds sound of obvious and stupid when I say it like this but thats all there is to it.

Comment: By definition, given a n.v.s $(G,\|\cdot\|)$, if $B\subset G$ is such that for all $f\in G'\quad$ $f(B)$ is bounded in $\mathbb{R}$, then $B$ is bounded in $G$.  don't understand why he isn't the testing the boundless on every element of the dual, but only on the elements of the basis

Comment: The condition in your criterion is hard to check. You have to check a whole bunch of functions. But because $\mathbb R^n$ has a richer structure than just of a vector space (i.e. it has a norm, an inner product blah blah), this simpler criterion is enough is what the theorem is saying.

Comment: Any idea to prove this fact?

Comment: I added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a function $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$. Suppose that $|(x,e_i)|=|x_i|\leq M$ for all $x= (x_1\cdots x_n)\in B$. Then $$|f(x)|=|f\left(\sum_{i=1}^n(x,e_i)e_i\right)|=|\left(\sum_{i=1}^n(x,e_i)f(e_i)\right)|\leq \sum_{i=1}^n|(x,e_i)||f(e_i)|$$
In the first equality, we are just using the fact that the $e_i$s form a basis.
The second equality comes from the linearity of $f$. The third is the triangle inequality. But the last sum is bounded **independently of ** $x$ because 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n|(x,e_i)||f(e_i)|\leq \sum_{i=1}^nM|f(e_i)|=M\sum_{i=1}^n|f(e_i)|.$$
This shows that each such $f$ in the dual space is bounded
You should prove the converse for yourself. Its a cool exercise (I've always wanted to say that).